# DNS hostname no longer resolves if a sub-hostname has been defined

Tags: domain-name-system, lets-encrypt, transip

I have trouble understanding a specific effect in DNS name resolution for subdomain names that came to light when enabling lets encrypt.

The context of my question:

I have a domain (basjes.nl) and I have set all hostnames in that domain to resolve to the same IP address.

In the UI of my DNS provider (Transip) I see something like this:

```
@                      A      x.x.x.x
*                      CNAME  @
```

Now I can do this to get the specified IP address.

```
dig blurp.basjes.nl
```

Recently I deployed the [ACME-DNS tool](https://github.com/joohoi/acme-dns) and setup the appropriate DNS entries (i.e. delegate auth.basjes.nl to my own ACME-DNS server) to allow Lets Encrypt to verify I own the specified hostname via DNS.

For this specific hostname I want to have a 'full name' HTTPS certificate (i.e. not the wild card) so I added something like this:

```
_acme-challenge.blurp  CNAME  something.auth.basjes.nl.
```

After adding this entry I find that doing `dig blurp.basjes.nl` no longer works. The strange thing is that I do not get an error (so no NXDOMAIN), I either get nothing or just

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
basjes.nl.      300 IN  SOA ns0.transip.net. hostmaster.transip.nl. 2018041107 14400 1800 2419200 300
```

So at this moment I have something like this:

```
@                      A      x.x.x.x
*                      CNAME  @
_acme-challenge.blurp  CNAME  something.auth.basjes.nl.
```

I have found that if I add an explicit DNS record for this hostname then suddenly it DOES work again:

```
@                      A      x.x.x.x
*                      CNAME  @
blurp                  CNAME  @
_acme-challenge.blurp  CNAME  something.auth.basjes.nl.
```

The effects I would like to understand:

- Why DOESN'T it resolve anymore when asking a normal DNS server ?

  The '*' record is still present!

  `dig blurp.basjes.nl @1.1.1.1`
- Why DOES it resolve when asking directly the SOA DNS server of Transip?

  `dig blurp.basjes.nl @ns0.transip.net`
- Why DOES it resolve when adding the explicit record?

  This is what I currently use as a workaround to make it work for me.

P.S. I have contacted Transip support before posting this question. They didn't know what went wrong here and/or why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNS is hierarchical. When you added the name `_acme-challenge.blurp.basjes.nl`, that meant that `blurp.basjes.nl` was also implicitly added. The bit here that may be surprising is that *a name can exist without having any content*. When you used `dig` to ask for `blurp.basjes.nl`, you got a perfectly correct and accurate answer: the name exists, but contains no records. This case, where a name exists only because there are other names below it in the DNS tree, is called an *empty non-terminal*. You can google that term if you want to know more.

That's the first part of your confusing behavior. The second part is this: a wildcard record is used to generate an answer if and only if the name asked for does not already exist. So, first you asked for `blurp.basjes.nl` and got an answer generated from the wildcard. Then you added `_acme-challenge.blurp.basjes.nl`. When you asked again after that, the name `blurp.basjes.nl` did exist (as described above), so the wildcard was not used. But since `blurp.basjes.nl` had no records in it, all you got back was an empty response. After that you added a `CNAME` record for `blurp.basjes.nl`, so when you asked yet again that's what you got back.

Does that clear things up?

Comment: Thank you. This clarifies the most important questions.. The last remaining thing I still don't understand is why the difference between asking 1.1.1.1 and the ns0.transip.net.

Comment: That almost certainly just a caching issue.

Comment: I double checked and it does not seem a caching issue. I suspect that it is simply a difference in handling an edge case like this in the various DNS servers/versions in relation with the need for recursion (i.e. is the server the authority of the domain or not).